# Easy example of a "non associative" ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there an easy example (one that an undergraduate math education student who learned the definition of a ring 5 minutes ago can understand) of a set who satisfies all the conditions of a ring except for associativity of multiplication?

Comment: The [octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion)?

Comment: Vectors in $\Bbb R^3$, using cross product as the multiplication, perhaps? (This doesn't have a multiplicative unit, so if your definition of ring requires that, then it doesn't work.)

Comment: You can get the ring of vectors.

Answer (score 3):

Let $R$ be a ring. The *commutator*
$$[·~·]\colon R × R → R,~(x,y) ↦ xy - yx$$
then defines an operation on $R$ which is trivial if and only if $R$ is commutative.

It is easy to check that this operation satisfies distributive laws. However, it has no unit in general.

If $R$ is non-commutative, this operation tends to be non-associative. For $x, y, z ∈ R$,
$$[[x~y]~z] = (xy - yx)z - z(xy - yx) ≠ x(yz - zy) - (yz - zy) x = [x~[y~z]]$$
if and only if
$$yxz + zxy ≠ xzy + yzx.$$

For example, if $x$ and $y$ are a symmetric pair of zero divisors, that is $xy = yx = 0$ and $z$ isolates them, the operation becomes non-associative. To specify further, take $x = [\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}]$, $y = [\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}]$ and $z = [\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 &0\end{smallmatrix}]$. Then $yxz + zyx = 0$, but $xzy + yzx ≠ 0$. (This assumes the student knows how to multiply matrices and recognizes matrix rings as rings.)

Comment: (Well, that operation has a unit in the [zero ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring).) ​ ​

Comment: On the other hand, every x satisfies ​ [x,x] = 0 , ​ so R being a zero ring is the $\hspace{1.87 in}$ _only_ way for the bracket to have an identity. ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 2):

You can get the ring of vectors with $\times$ because for all $a$, $b$ and $c$ we obtain:
$$(a\times b)\times c+(b\times c)\times a+(c\times a)\times b=0.$$

Comment: That gives a [rng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra)), not a ring. ​ ​

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics) This structure apply all axioms.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg In the "Definitions" section of your link, item two, the second bullet is not fulfilled. There is no $1$ in this ring. So no, this structure doesn't "apply all axioms".

Comment: I think it's not necessary for ring. At least my teacher (professor Dorofeev) said it. OK. If now it's not a ring I'll delete my post. Or maybe Wikipedia wrong?

Comment: @RickyDemer Some authors allow rings to be non-unital. The questioner has so far not specified if he or she wishes the ring to be unital or not.

Comment: @Arthur you might find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)#Multiplicative_identity:_mandatory_vs._optional) article interesting.

Comment: @P.Siehr I know that there are varying conventions. See, for instance, my comment to the original question post. _However_, when Rozenberg claims that this structure fulfills all ring axioms and links to the Wikipedia article where the unit requirement is spelled out explicitly, then that is wrong without further explanation and contextualization.

Comment: I think, now you understood all points. If you wish, you can fix my post. I don't want to do it. Also, I need to say to you that my name is Michael.

Comment: Non unital ring is fine. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a non-associative ring.

Let's call it $R$.

Start with the free Abelian group on two generators $x$ and $y$.

Define an operation $*$ in the following way.

- $x*x = y$
- $x*y = 0$
- $y*x = 0$
- $y*y = x$

Additionally, note that the following two equations hold, which can be used to define $*$ on terms headed by $-$, noting that $a + b$ is equivalent to $a - (0 - b)$.

- $(a - b) * c = (a * c) - (b * c)$
- $a * (b - c) = (a * b) - (a * c)$

We can use the triple $(x, y, y)$ to witness the non-associativity of $R$.

$$ x * (y * y) = x * x = y $$
$$ (x * y) * y = 0 * y = 0 $$